# Scaldi dependency injection with Constructor

Tags: scala, scaldi

I have three classes class A, class B and class C. I want to inject Class A and Class B as a dependency through constructor to Class C. I am using ScalDI dependency injection framework. Can someone tell me how I can do it?

```
class A {
...}
class B {
..}
class C(a:A , b:B) = {
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is short explanation on scaldi website:
[constructor injection](http://scaldi.org/learn/#constructor-injection)

You have to use `injected` macro, or inject them in the following fashion:

```
bind [C] to new C(inject [A], inject [B])
```

Of Course binding to A and B have to be defined as well.